# How to fix Magento time stamp issue on lower version of SQL

Tags: mysql, magento2

How to fix Magento time stamp issue on lower version of SQL?

I have fixed below as per

```
`modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'User Modified Time'
```

to

```
`modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'User Modified Time'
```

Now want to know how to fix

1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `integration`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `integration` (
  `integration_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Integration ID',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Integration name is displayed in the admin interface',
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Email address of the contact person',
  `endpoint` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Endpoint for posting consumer credentials',
  `status` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Integration status',
  `consumer_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Oauth consumer',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Creation Time',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Update Time',
  `setup_type` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Integration type - manual or config file',
  `identity_link_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Identity linking Url',
  PRIMARY KEY (`integration_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `INTEGRATION_NAME` (`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `INTEGRATION_CONSUMER_ID` (`consumer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='integration';
```

## `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Update Time',

Comment: What version of MySQL is this?

Comment: My DB is Server version: 5.7.24 and going to upload on Server version: 5.4

Comment: Does removing this part works ?

DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Yes, '0000...' isn't a valid time (even if old versions accepted this). Have you tried removing that part? Does your application place a time in updated_at? Maybe `NULL` would be a better default. Does you application handle `NULL`?
Deploying to 5.4 are you serious/mad? Was this ever a GA product? Even [5.5 is EOL](https://endoflife.software/applications/databases/mysql). You seem to have tested on 5.7 so why not deploy on that?